# Is this the right way to blink a character on LCD?

Tags: c++, lcd

The code is this:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);

unsigned long blinkTime = 0;
int ValueA = 22;
String placeHolder = "  ";

void setup() {
  lcd.begin();
}

void loop() {
  lcd.setCursor(7, 0);
  if (millis() - blinkTime > 2000) {
    lcd.print(ValueA);
    blinkTime = millis();
  }
  if (millis() - blinkTime > 1000) {
    lcd.print(placeHolder);
  }
}
```

The I2C LCD library have a `lcd.blink()` function but it seems that only blinks a "cursor".

The problem with above code is the `placeHolder`, what if `ValueA` gets bigger than 2 digits?

Is there a better way to blink a value on LCD?

Comment: tip: `lcd.setCursor(7, 0);` is in both `if` blocks ... use it before the first `if` instead

Comment: @jsotola Done, thanks.

Comment: write a function that accepts three parameters ... boolean `show`, byte `position` and int `value` .... `value` is the data to display ... `position` is location of displayed data ... `show` if true, display data, if false, display spaces ..... `show` is set by a timer function at the beginning of loop()

Comment: @jsotola I've never wrote a function before, can you please post an example of what you just described?

Comment: google arduino functions ... https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/FunctionDeclaration

Comment: The LCD module has this feature built in. There is no need to implement yourself. Call `lcd.blink();` and the current cursor position will blink.

Comment: it's blinking the cursor, i want to blink the character...!

Comment: Instead of redrawing you could periodically turn the display on and off.

Comment: @MikaelPatel turning the display on off? what do you mean?

Comment: You could use the back-light control instead of rewriting the display to create the illusion of blinking the text (all).

Comment: @MikaelPatel but that will blink the whole screen not a 2 or 3 digit character, right? plus i want to keep the backlight ON...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To blink a number (alternate between the number and empty space(s)), you could try the `BlinkLCD` class in this sketch. It only works with numbers from 0 to 4294967295 or text (`char` array, 16 characters max). It does not work with floating point numbers.

```
// 4540 bytes.
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);

class BlinkLCD{

  private:

    byte m_blinkState, m_startPosition, m_dataLength;
    unsigned long m_dataToBlink, m_previousMillis, m_blinkRate;
    char m_text[16 + 1];

  public:

    BlinkLCD(): m_blinkState(0), m_startPosition(0), m_dataLength(0),
                m_dataToBlink(0), m_previousMillis(0), m_blinkRate(500),
                m_text(){}

    void Update(){

      unsigned long m_currentMillis = millis();

      if(m_currentMillis - m_previousMillis >= m_blinkRate){

        byte m_row = 0;
        m_blinkState = !m_blinkState;
        m_previousMillis = m_currentMillis;

        if(m_startPosition > 15){
          m_startPosition -= 16;
          m_row = 1;
        }

        lcd.setCursor(m_startPosition, m_row);

        if(m_blinkState){
          if((unsigned)strlen(m_text) > 0){
            lcd.print(m_text);
          }
          else{
            lcd.print(m_dataToBlink);
          }
        }
        else{
          for(byte i = 0; i < m_dataLength; i++){
            lcd.print(" ");
          }
        }
      }
    }

    void SetBlinkRate(unsigned long blinkRate){
      m_blinkRate = blinkRate;
    }

    void SetNumber(unsigned long dataToBlink){
      m_dataToBlink = dataToBlink;
    }

    void SetLength(byte dataLength){
      m_dataLength = dataLength;
    }

    // LCD top row, columns 0 - 15
    // LCD Bottom row, 16 - 31
    void SetStartPosition(byte startPosition){
      m_startPosition = startPosition;
    }

    void SetText(char text[]){
      strcpy(m_text, text);
    }

};

BlinkLCD TopRowLCD;
BlinkLCD BottomRowLCD;
BlinkLCD BottomRowLCDtext;

void setup(){
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Temperature 35 C");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Num = 4294967295");
}

void loop(){

  // Simulate sensor data.
  static byte counter = 35;
  static unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  // Update the temperature reading every 2 seconds.
  if(currentMillis - previousMillis >= 2000){
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    counter++;
    if(counter > 45){counter = 35;}
    lcd.setCursor(12, 0);
    lcd.print(counter);
  }

  // Blink the temperature reading if it's over 40 C.
  if(counter > 40){
    TopRowLCD.SetNumber(counter);
    TopRowLCD.SetStartPosition(12);
    TopRowLCD.SetLength(2);
    TopRowLCD.SetBlinkRate(250);
    TopRowLCD.Update();
  }

  // Blink a number on the second row of the LCD
  // with a default blink rate of 500ms ON, 500ms OFF.
  BottomRowLCD.SetNumber(4294967295);
  BottomRowLCD.SetStartPosition(22);
  BottomRowLCD.SetLength(10);
  BottomRowLCD.Update();

  // Blink some text with at the default blink rate.
  BottomRowLCDtext.SetText("Num");
  BottomRowLCDtext.SetStartPosition(16);
  BottomRowLCDtext.SetLength(3);
  BottomRowLCDtext.Update();

}
```